# Java resource files are missing when I build my android library with gradle and proguard

Tags: android, gradle, proguard, aar

the java resources are packed to the jar without any problem when I do a debug build. However, it doesn't work with release builds. I noticed that the gradle task processReleaseJavaRes is only executed for debug builds. I searched the android gradle code and found the following [lines of code:](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/build/+/e8a18c6ee8e4c93df093c00224fdd3b024ed5774/gradle/src/main/groovy/com/android/build/gradle/LibraryPlugin.groovy#285)

```
if (variantConfig.buildType.runProguard) {
    // run proguard on output of compile task
    createProguardTasks(variantData, null)
    // hack since bundle can't depend on variantData.proguardTask
    mergeProGuardFileTask.dependsOn variantData.proguardTask
    bundle.dependsOn packageRes, packageAidl, packageRenderscript, mergeProGuardFileTask, lintCopy, variantData.ndkCompileTask
} else {
    Sync packageLocalJar = project.tasks.create("package${variantData.variantConfiguration.fullName.capitalize()}LocalJar",Sync)
    packageLocalJar.from(getLocalJarFileList(variantData.variantDependency))
    packageLocalJar.into(project.file("$project.buildDir/$DIR_BUNDLES/${variantData.variantConfiguration.dirName}/$SdkConstants.LIBS_FOLDER"))
    // jar the classes.
    Jar jar = project.tasks.create("package${buildType.name.capitalize()}Jar", Jar);
    jar.dependsOn variantData.javaCompileTask, variantData.processJavaResourcesTask
    jar.from(variantData.javaCompileTask.outputs);
    jar.from(variantData.processJavaResourcesTask.destinationDir)
    ...
    bundle.dependsOn packageRes, jar, packageAidl, packageRenderscript, packageLocalJar, mergeProGuardFileTask, lintCopy, variantData.ndkCompileTask
    ...
}
```

I then tried to add the task as a dependecy of proguardRelease:

```
tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name.matches("proguardRelease")) {
        task.dependsOn('processReleaseJavaRes')
    }
}
```

This works great and the java resources were created in build/intermediates/javaResources/ - but then the next problem occured. How can I tell proguard that it should build the jar with the classes from build/intermediates/classes and also include the resources from build/intermediates/javaResources? I tried to set the javaResources path with -injars. Now they are added to proguard (see log output below), but are not added to the classes.jar in build/intermediate/bundles/release/classes.jar.

```
13:32:30.731 [INFO] [system.out] Reading program directory [/path/to/my/project/build/intermediates/classes/release] (filtered)
13:32:30.913 [INFO] [system.out] Reading program directory [/path/to/my/project/build/intermediates/javaResources/release]
```

Thanks in advance,
Romanski

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem, and [filed an issue for the project](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=188994&thanks=188994&ts=1444217495)

In the meantime, I used the following snippet to workaround the issue:

```
android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->

    def proguardTask = variant.obfuscation
        if (proguardTask != null) {
            proguardTask.doFirst {
                copy {
                    from variant.processJavaResources.destinationDir
                    into variant.javaCompile.destinationDir
                }
            }
        }
}
```

It will copy the java res folder to the `classes` folder, and it will be included in the final jar.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a solution, but I made a workaround for the problem: I just run the task manually and then create a jar from the java resources and the obfuscated jar file:

```
android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputFile = file("${project.buildDir}/outputs/aar/${project.archivesBaseName}-${variant.baseName}.aar");

    if(variant.buildType.name.matches("release")) {
        tasks.create(name: "enriched${variant.name.capitalize()}Jar", type:Jar, dependsOn:variant.processJavaResources) {
            from zipTree("${project.buildDir}/intermediates/bundles/${variant.dirName}/classes.jar") // add original content
            from fileTree("${project.buildDir}/intermediates/javaResources/${variant.dirName}/")
            destinationDir(file("${project.buildDir}/intermediates/bundles/${variant.dirName}/"))
            includeEmptyDirs false
            archiveName 'classes_full.jar'
        }

        tasks.create(name: "fix${variant.name.capitalize()}Files", type:Delete, dependsOn:"enriched${variant.name.capitalize()}Jar") {
            delete "${project.buildDir}/intermediates/bundles/${variant.dirName}/classes.jar"
            doLast{
                file("${project.buildDir}/intermediates/bundles/${variant.dirName}/classes_full.jar").renameTo(file("${project.buildDir}/intermediates/bundles/${variant.dirName}/classes.jar"))
            }
        }

        variant.packageLibrary.dependsOn "fix${variant.name.capitalize()}Files"
        tasks["fix${variant.name.capitalize()}Files"].mustRunAfter variant.obfuscation
    }
}
```